# see if a c# session contains a specific value

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I woud like to see if a c# session contains a specific value

For example :

```
public Void CheckSession(string string1){
if(["Session1"].Contains(string1)){

//Do this
}
}
```

Comment: Why it is tagged to `c#` as well as `javascript`?  what you meant by `Session` is this ASP session or its javascript array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["sessionname"] as string))
{
     if(Session["sessionname"].ToString().Contains(string1));
}
```

you need to [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) this first

Comment: Your code will throw error if `Session["sessionname"]` is null

Comment: ohh wow was just missing the cast , of .toString() ill check this and if it works ill let you know and give you the credit

Comment: @sujithkarivelil ill check before hand

Comment: ok please try the solution now,make sure your are using correct session name